# bash - java .jar in for loop overwrites my output file

Tags: bash, for-loop, jar

I created a bash script to run .jar files in a for loop in 3 files I have in the directory: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
module load Java/jre1.8.0_74
cd /mydirectory
for fname in *.txt
    do
    java -jar myjar.jar "$fname" > "$fname".log
    done
```

The problem is that I would like to create several "$fname".log files (1.txt.log, 2.txt.log, 3.txt.log) and the script is overwriting my log files.

Comment: Am sure it does not overwrite, it could create as `1.txt.log` and so on? Are you sure of this

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. It does create 1.txt.log, but then it is removed when 2.txt.log is created. weird

Comment: Are you by chance running the script from the `/tmp` folder?

Comment: my script includes a cd /mydirectory before the for loop

Comment: Post the entire script.  As far as what you posted, I do not see why 1.txt.log would get erased by creating 2.txt.log.  Does your myjar.jar code delete files?

Comment: I edited the script to include the missing info. No, the myjar.jar file does not delete files.